# App crashed with cursor getInt

Tags: android

I want to get number of rows inside a table using a `SELECT COUNT(*) as nb` query. Then when I want to get the result by using `cursor.getInt(0)` then the app crashed ! So I replaced my code with this :

```
public int getParcelleCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + T_PARCELLE;
    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int nb = 0;
    if (cursor != null) {
        nb = cursor.getCount();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return nb;
}
```

And it works ! So why is the first option wrong ?

Comment: Put your code in try catch block ...and post your logcat..

Comment: If all you want to do is get the number of rows in a Cursor object, then you simply need to call getCount() on it.

Comment: but what should be the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous code did not work because you were trying to get values without moving to first. You have check for not null that was correct. But it was throwing **Cursor Index Out Of Bounds Exception**(You can search on internet). So you have to move cursor to first and then try to get values.

Try below code.

```
String countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NB FROM " + T_PARCELLE;
Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
int nb = 0;

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do
   {
       nb = cursor.getInt(0);

       }while(cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   cursor.close();
   return nb;
```

Comment: I explained my answer which apparently was your original question that why your code was crashing the application. @Pheromix